# I cannot get javascript's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I cannot get javascript's value.I wrote in index.html

```
<body>
　  <form method="post" action="">
    <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
    {% for i in json_data.items.values %}
            <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>

    {% for key, values in preprocessed %}
    <select name="type" id=type{{forloop.counter}}>
    {% for counter, value in values %}
        <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{ value }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mainDD').on('change', function() {
              var thisType = "type" + $(this).val();
              for(i=1; i<6; i++) {
                  var thisId = "type" + i;
                  if(thisType !== thisId) {
                    $("#"+thisId).hide();
                  }
                  else {
                    $("#"+thisId).show();
                  }
              }

            }).trigger('change');

        });


  </script>

     <form id="postform" action="http://localhost:8000/app/test_view" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="SEND">
     </form>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $('[name=type]').change(function() {
    　　var key;
        var value;
        $('select[name="main"] option:selected').each(function(index, option) {
            var key = $(option).text();
            console.log(key); //A
        });

        $('select[name="type"] option:selected').each(function(index, option) {
            var value = $(option).text();
            console.log(value); //A
        });
        console.log(key); //B
        console.log(value); //B
          document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").onclick = e => {
           const test = window.open(`test_view?${key}=${value}`, "_blank");
          }
     });
     </script>
  </body>
```

I wanna get i& value variables `console.log(key);` & `console.log(value);` with //B,but now undefined is `shown.console.log(key);` & `console.log(value);` with //A is shown ideal values I really cannot understand why I can not get these values in last console.log.How should I fix this? What should I write it?

New javascript codes is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('[name=type]').change(function() {
    　　var key;
        var value;
        $('select[name="main"] option:selected').each(function(index, option) {
            key = $(option).text();
        });

        $('select[name="type"] option:selected').each(function(index, option) {
            value = $(option).text();
        });
        console.log(key);
        console.log(value);
          document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").onclick = e => {
           const test = window.open(`test_view?${key}=${value}`, "_blank");
          }
     });
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mainDD').on('change', function() {
              var thisType = "type" + $(this).val();
              for(i=1; i<6; i++) {
                  var thisId = "type" + i;
                  if(thisType !== thisId) {
                    $("#"+thisId).hide();
                  }
                  else {
                    $("#"+thisId).show();
                  }
              }

            }).trigger('change');

        });

     </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be a few problems with your code:

1. You have `key` and `value` declared as a `var` in the start of `$('[name=type]').change` but then you declare them again just a bit later `var key = $(option).text()` so the first `key` will never get a value.
2. You also try to get the value of the selected option from a `select` with the name main, but in your HTML you don't have one with that name.
3. Also if your **NOT** using `multiple` in your `select` then you can get the selected value of a select by using `key = $('select[name="main"]').val();`, no reason to use `.each()`

I've changed your code and made a working example below.

```js
$('[name=type]').change(function() {　　
  var key;
  var value;
  $('select[name="main"] option:selected').each(function(index, option) {
    key = $(option).text();
    console.log(key + " (A) "); //A
  });

  $('select[name="type"] option:selected').each(function(index, option) {
    value = $(option).text();
    console.log(value + " (A) "); //A
  });
  console.log(key + " (B) "); //B
  console.log(value + " (B) "); //B
  document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").onclick = e => {
    const test = window.open(`test_view?${key}=${value}`, "_blank");
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mainDD').on('change', function() {
    var thisType = "type" + $(this).val();
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
      var thisId = "type" + i;
      if (thisType !== thisId) {
        $("#" + thisId).hide();
      } else {
        $("#" + thisId).show();
      }
    }

  }).trigger('change');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mainDD" name="main" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

<select name="type" id=type1>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

<form id="postform" action="http://localhost:8000/app/test_view" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

Comment: thx ur answer,I can get `key` value, but cannot get  `value` value.How can I fix this?

Comment: did you remove `var` from `var value = $(option).text();`

Comment: yes, i did.So I really cannot understand why this error happens.

Comment: @user8681386 Try updated your question with the new jquery. then i might be able to point out the problem

Comment: I updated my codes.if u know something, please help me

Comment: try add this line and see if you get a value `console.log($('select[name="type"]').val();)`

Comment: I cannot get a value console.log($('select[name="type"]').val();). So how can I fix this?

Comment: @user8681386 It should work, so it must be somethign with your html or js, kinda hard to help from here

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the var keyword inside the loops.  Because you have redefine the key,value variables inside the loop again. You can try this code.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('[name=type]').change(function() {
　   　var key;
      var value;
    $('select[name="main"] option:selected').each(function(index, option) {
        key = $(option).text();
        console.log(key); //A
    });

    $('select[name="type"] option:selected').each(function(index, option) {
        value = $(option).text();
        console.log(value); //A
    });
    console.log(key); //B
    console.log(value); //B
      document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").onclick = e => {
       const test = window.open(`test_view?${key}=${value}`, "_blank");
      }
  });
  </script>
```